# Package name does not correspond to the file path - IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, package, project-structure

I'm trying to import a project from VCS (well, I'm doing it for the first time actually) and this is my (imported) project's structure:

[image: The file structure]

BTW. this screen is made after many tries of changing these directories' properties (in their context menus).

In these source files' I have a following error:

[image: The error in the editor]

One time it had nothing against `badugi.client` but it reported this error only in `badugi.server`. I have completely no idea how it works...

Also classes in the same directories do not see each other.

[image: Error]

This is a code from `ClientWorker` class which is located (as you can see in the first image) in the same directory as `Server` so it should know what `Server` is.

I'm pretty sure this code worked well in my friend's IDE. How do I configure IntelliJ to make it work?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Judging from the directory structure, you have two packages client and server, but the code expects packages badugi.client and badugi.server.

Here is a way to fix it:

1. Position your cursor to the underlined package statement (`package badugi.server`)
2. Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Select option *Move to package badugi.server*. This will automatically fix your directory structure to match the declared package

or

1. Right click src in Project explorer
2. Select *New/Package* and create package badugi
3. Select client and server packages and drag them to the badugi package

Comment: What should I do if I have like, 50 classes and all are to be moved to the package? Is there a way or I just have to manually Alt+Enter them all?

Answer (score 86):

I had this same issue, and fixed it by modifying my project's .iml file:

From:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/wrong/entry/here" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
</content>
```

To:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
</content>
```

Somehow a package folder became specified as the root source directory when this project was imported.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You wouldn't want to go changing file structure of an application that works in production (likely causing you to have to rework the build process). Rather, you should change your IDE so that it figures it out appropriately.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. This was the actual solution to my problem.

Comment: Thanks, Trann. Also, by the same logic you can edit it via settings using Intelij IDEA: `File -> Project Structure -> Modules` and mark as `Sources` correct path instead.

Comment: Are IML files suitable for sharing via source control? Our project has them in `.gitignore`. And I see an `external.linked.project.id` attribute on the root `module` element that refers to the name of the directory the project is in (which is specific to that _copy_). I like this solution, but only if it doesn't have to be repeated for every copy.

Comment: In my case, I have solved the issue by changing
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
into
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/java" isTestSource="false" />

Quick and effective! Thanks for this answer

Comment: this makes me want to commit the *.iml file to source control. This is the worst.

Answer (score 21):

I've seen this error a few times too, and I've always been able to solve it by correctly identifying the project's module settings. In IntelliJ, right-click on the top level project -> "Open Module Settings". This should open up a window with the entire project structure and content identified as "Source Folders", "Test Source Folders", etc. Make sure these are correctly set. For the "Source Folders", ensure that the folder is your src/ or src/java (or whatever your source language is), as the case may be

Comment: this saved my week. may god bless you fellow human.

Answer (score 13):

Add this to `pom.xml`(inside the `project` tag)

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

`src/main/java` is the source folder you want to set. If you already have this line in your `pom.xml` file, check if it's correct.

Comment: For my case, I changed from   <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> to   <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

Comment: super1ha1@ you saved me some previous time there! Thank you.

Comment: For my point, this was the correct answer. After that you have to right click your project folder in the overview, go to your compiler section and click "Reload project".

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to tell Intellij to ignore this error.

File > Settings > Editor > Inspections, then search for "Wrong package statement" (Under Java, Probable Bugs) on the right and uncheck it.

Comment: I'm upvoting this one because my folder structure is correct (and gradle compiles my Java fine) and Android-Studio has the error

Comment: I upvoted this because in Scala it is allowed to have package and file path to differ. One thing that I would add is that instead of to uncheck it maybe move the flag level from `error` to `warn` or `silent warn`. Note that Scala and Java settings are separated.

Comment: I find it troublesome that IntelliJ has this setting on, as an error, by default. Scala allows flatter directory structures and there are benefits for using them (if one works also in terminal, not only in the IDE).

Answer (score 4):

You should declare in the Project structure(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+s) in the Module section mark your folders which of them are source package(blue one) and which are test ...

Comment: I've added it as the source package, but it keeps changing back, I don't know why.

Comment: @Searene: Invalidate cache and restart may help you

Comment: It's Cmd-; on Mac :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues due to corrupted or maybe outdated intellij files. Before updating to 14.0.2 I had a perfectly working project with CORRECTLY named packages and file hierarchies.

After the update, maven compilations worked without a hitch but Intellij was reporting the said error on a specific package (other packages with similar characteristics were not affected).

I didn't bother to investigate much further , but **I deleted my .iml files and .idea folders, invalidated caches, restarted the IDE, and reopened the project**, relying on my maven configuration.

**NOTE: This, effectively deletes run and debug configurations!**

Maybe someone who understands the intellij workspace files could comment on this?

Another comment for those searching into this further: Refactoring in SC managed projects can leave behind dust -- I happen to have an "old" folder which has repetitions of the current package structure. If the .iml or .idea files have any reference to these packages it's likely that intellij could get confused with references to old packages. Good luck, fellow StackExchangers.

**Update: I deleted some files in a referenced maven project and the quirk has returned. So, my post is by no means a final answer.**

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin

For those using Kotlin who are following the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-code-organization) package conventions:

> In pure Kotlin projects, the recommended directory structure is to follow the package structure with the common root package omitted (e.g. if all the code in the project is in the "org.example.kotlin" package and its subpackages, files with the "org.example.kotlin" package should be placed directly under the source root, and files in "org.example.kotlin.foo.bar" should be in the "foo/bar" subdirectory of the source root).

[IntelliJ doesn't support this yet](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/root-package-declaration-to-reduce-folder-clutter/2247). The only thing you can do is to disable this warning, and accept that the IDE will not help you with refactorings when it comes to changing folders/files structures.

Answer (score 1):

I created a package under folder src which resolved this problem.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxUOn.png)

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_XxH66lm3U&t=168s) at timestamp 2:48 helped me.

Try creating a new Java class with the IntelliJ interface whose name is `com.example.packagename.YOUR_CLASS_NAME`.

Then IntelliJ automatically created the package correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was just fighting with similar problem. My way to solve it was to set the root source file for Intellij module to match the original project root folder. Then i needed to mark some folders as Excluded in project navigation panel (the one that should not be used in new one project, for me it was part used under Android). That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone encounters a similar warning I had with a Scala project.

> Package names doesn't correspond to directories structure, this may cause problems with resolve to classes from this file
>   Inspection for files with package statement which does not correspond to package structure.

The file was in the right location, so the helper solutions the IDE provides are not helpful[image]
The Move File says file already exists (which is true) and Rename Package would actually move it to the incorrect package.

The problem is that if you have Scala Objects, you have to make sure that the first object in the file has the same name as the filename, so the solution is to move the objects inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and in my case the fix was removing the '-' character from project name. Instead of `my-app`, I used `MyApp`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was I had refactored a package to a different name and for some reason IntelliJ had reverted that (even though the package name, in terms of git tracking, had not changed). I refactored it once more to the new name and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create another `Package` and move all folders to its ! all error will remove

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just to rename the first line in each class.

For example

[image: Package name does not correspond to the file path]

IntelliJ tells us that the package name should be "module09.nationalratswahlen"

The current name is "oop2.module09.nationalratswahlen"

Just press Control-Shift-R and replace "oop2.module09" with "module09" in all files. However normally you should just clone a repository by File > New > Project from Version control. Then you would avoid such issues.

Answer (score -1):

This is tricky here. In my case, the folder structure was:

> com/appName/rateUS/models/FileName.java

The package name, which I had specified in the file FileName.java was:

```
package com.appName.rateUs.models;
```

Notice the subtle difference between the package name: it should have been **rateUS** instead of rateU**s**

Hope this helps someone!