# Why is my maven generate command for JMH generating POMs and a Java class which contain errors?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, jmh

I am using the following code:

mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype -DgroupId=org.sample -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0

This generates the following file structure (inside of my current cd location):

-test

```
-src.main.java.org.sample

   -MyBenchmark.java

-pom.xml
```

The generated files have the following error:
MyBenchmark:
Package name 'org.sample' does not correspond to the file path 'com.example.benchmark_coursework.test.src.main.java.org.sample'

pom:
(no actual error message, it just appears in red)

I am using IntelliJ and my overall objective is to generate a jar file to execute JMH Benchmarks that i have made to time various methods. I have tried looking at the root pom file but there are no errors i can see. I have tried CDing into various other parts of my directory too. Mvn clean install and running the jar file from my main class works fine, getting the benchmarks to work as well does not. Any assistance is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38892053/8203759
If it does not help, share a sample project where this could be reproduced.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.